# django view variable matching to a queryset

Tags: python, django

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, but I didn't know how else to word it, first I will show you my code.

```
def page(request, page_lang='eng', page_title='home'):

    page_lang = SiteLanguage.objects.get(title=page_lang)
    context = {
        'page_lang': page_lang,
        'page_content': page_lang.page_title
    }
```

So in my context I want to have the key 'page_content' match with the value page_lang.home so I can avoid putting a bunch of logic into the code. Can this be done?

Comment: if page_lang is a string then what is page_lang.home

Comment: I think your variable naming is confusing

Comment: it is some content that I wish to have displayed on the home page. I just can't figure out how to add that string onto the lookup

Comment: Try to use different variables (page_lang and page_lang)

Comment: I understand why it seems confusing, but in my head I am just renaming the variable to a larger object which contains all the page_lang info. The function arg is just a lookup method

Comment: do you want something like context = {'page_lang': page_lang, page_lang.home: page_lang.page_title}? The question is rather confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and `page_lang` should be renamed to `page_lang_name`

```
def page(request, page_lang_name='eng', page_title='home'):
    page_lang_obj = SiteLanguage.objects.get(title=page_lang_name)
    context = {
        'page_lang': page_lang_obj,
        'page_content': getattr(page_lang_obj, page_title) 
    }
```